# Find the distribution of $Y$ given that $Y>0$

Tags: probability-theory

Given that $Y=max(0,4-X)$, where $X\sim N(0,1)$. Find the CDF of $Y$ and the conditional density of $Y$ given  that $Y>0$.

Knowing that  $Y=0$  if  $X\geq 4$ and $Y=4-X$  if  $X< 4$
$$P(Y>y|Y>0)=\frac{P(Y>y,Y>0)}{P(Y>0)}\\
=\frac{P(X<4-y,X<4)}{P(X<4)}\\
=\frac{\Phi(4-y)}{\Phi(4)}.$$

So we have $$P(Y\leq y|Y>0)=1-\frac{\Phi(4-y)}{\Phi(4)}.$$ So  the conditional density is
$$ f(y)=\frac{1}{\Phi(4)} \cdot \phi(4-y).$$

Is that what you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: go for finding $P(Y>y\mid Y>0)$ instead of finding $P(Y\leq y\mid Y>0)$.

Comment: @Kofi Consider adding your comment to the question with an [edit]. People may not see the comments, and may downvote or vote to close on the basis of not seeing any attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Brian. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @drhab. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Except that you should add that this is true for $y\geq0$. For $y <0$ you can go for $f(y)=0$.

Comment: @drhab Noted. Thanks